# Multiple files and parameter upload using retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, image-uploading, retrofit2

I'm trying to upload 3 images and 4 parameters in single request:

**Try 1**

```
@Multipart
    @POST("example/upload")
    Call<String> upload(@Part("param_1") String param1,
                             @Part("param_2") String param2,
                             @Part("param_3") String param3,
                             @Part("param_4") String param4,
                             @Part("param_5") String param5,
                             @Part("image_1") okhttp3.RequestBody image1Jpg,
                             @Part("image_2") okhttp3.RequestBody image2Jpg,
                             @Part("another_image") okhttp3.RequestBody anotherImageJpg);
```

**Try 2**

```
@Multipart
    @POST("example/upload")
    Call<String> upload(@PartMap() Map<String, okhttp3.RequestBody> data,
                                   @Part okhttp3.MultipartBody.Part image1,
                                   @Part okhttp3.MultipartBody.Part image2,
                                   @Part okhttp3.MultipartBody.Part anotherImage);
```

**Try 3**

```
@Multipart
    @POST("example/upload")
    Call<String> upload(@PartMap() Map<String, okhttp3.RequestBody> data,
                             @Part("image_1") okhttp3.RequestBody image1Jpg,
                             @Part("image_2") okhttp3.RequestBody image2Jpg,
                             @Part("another_image") okhttp3.RequestBody anotherImageJpg);
```

**The below methods that I've passed to upload methods**

```
public static RequestBody createRequestBody(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
        return RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse(MULTIPART_FROM_DATA), out.toByteArray());
    }


public static MultipartBody.Part createPart(String name, String fileName, Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
        RequestBody data = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse(MULTIPART_FROM_DATA), out.toByteArray());
        MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(name, fileName, data);
        return part;
    }
```

I got the 400 Bad Request error but the server side is fine by testing with POSTMAN.

What am I wrong?
Any idea would be appreciate.